# where does dynamic memory variable live in memory in the following situation?

Tags: memory, operating-system, stack, heap-memory

Let's say what have a dynamic memory variable which we created using malloc.

```
dynamic_memory_variable = malloc(byte_size)
```

That dynamic memory is obviously allocated on heap, however where does dynamic_memory_variable live?

If I am not mistaken, it is a local variable living on stack because it is now a local variable for the function call? Am I correct in presuming that?

Comment: ..assuming it's a local variable at all.   You can malloc to global and static pointers, should you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, `dynamic_memory_variable will` is only a variable/pointer to the memory. The variable will only live on the stack, but the memory where it's referencing to is on the heap. If you lose the pointer, the memory is still allocated, but not accessible, nor deallocable anymore.